# Downloading Saved Data on the iCloud

Tags: xcode, core-data, icloud

I'm new to syncing data from iCloud so I have been using different tutorials to figure out how to upload my Core Data database to the iCloud. To do this I used a GitHub Source Code (https://github.com/mluisbrown/iCloudCoreDataStack). According to the Debug menu on Xcode 5 I am uploading Data to the iCloud and then it shows it is downloading however I see no data being returned, I think this is because I have nothing implemented in the `-(void)storesDidChange:(NSNotification *)note` method. I have no clue how to put this data into practice. Please let me know if there is anything you need from me and I'll be happy to get it to you! Thank You!

Comment: Have a look at this link, there is a video and sample code showing how to sync using iCloud.  I use UIManagedDocument so setting up the core data stack is a bit different but processing the log import notifications will be the same.  Look in the Document Manager code so see how these notifications are handled.  http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/uimanageddocument-icloud-integration/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard Core Data iCloud issue and is not impacted by the code you are using.

You need to consume that notification when it comes back.  You do this with your main `NSManagedObjectContext` using the method `-[NSManagedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:]`.  This will cause your `NSManagedObjectContext` to tickle any `NSFetchedResultsController` instances that you have.

Answer (score 1):

I am also using PersistanceStack. In `storesDidChange:`, I simply post a notification to the notification center. This is caught by any active view controller displaying any relevant data.

In the view controller I simply update the Interface, e.g. by performing a fetch on the fetched results controller and/or reloading a table view.

Comment: Can you give me a example of what you are doing. That would be very helpful, I apologize I am very new to CoreData and iCloud

Comment: There is really nothing to it. Just learn how to post and listen to notifications. Look up the docs of [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).